# How can I create a child with a given ID and value in Firebase in Android Studio? android - firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make a new child in firebase with android studio

`var dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
dbref.child("chat").push().child(id).setValue(txt)`

I used the code above and it looks like the picture below.

[image]

I want to create multiple ids with a value of txt under 'chat'.

But when I put push() in front of child(), strange value replaces id value and txt is not included.

This is what I want, but how do I get this?

chat

->id:txt

->me:hello

.

.

.

I'm using the Google Translator, so it can be awkward. But, as far as I know, this place the only place to ask this question.

Comment: So you don't need that pushed id?

Answer (score 0):

the answer for your question is:

- First create a model class like ChatModel(), that model will contain all the information inside that child "-M94B...". Then on your code pass the values to a empty ChatModel() variable like:

```
    val chatModel = ChatModel()
    chatModel.info1 = yourInfoVariable1
    chatModel.info2 = yourInfoVariable2
               .
               .
               .
```

and so on until you complete all of the data needed on that child. Then, you just need to pass it to your reference like:

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("YOUR_CHAT_REFERENCE")
        .child("HERE_YOU_PLACE_THE_ID_YOU_WANT")
        .setValue(chatModel)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                //Execute a code if the data is updated in firebase
                Toast.makeText(context!!, "Data Updated", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()
            }
        .addOnFailureListener { 
            Toast.makeText(context!!, "Some error has ocurred!",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show()
        }
```

These lines of code: ".child("HERE_YOU_PLACE_THE_ID_YOU_WANT").setValue(chatModel)" will set the UID you want for the child created, you just need to replace "HERE_YOU_PLACE_THE_ID_YOU_WANT" with your own UID.